# How does mariaDB stored mediumText

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I am using mariaDB(10.5.15) , I have a table with structure like

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT,
    entityId varchar(50),
    encrypted_file mediumtext,
    created_at datetime,
    updated_at datetime
);
```

Initially , I was encrypting and storing the xml file in encrypted_file column , on an average the file size was around 120KB , so reduce the file size I started to compress it and store , the average size of compressed file was around 10 KB. To store in  the DB I created a new column encrypted_file_v2 and start storing it in the new column and for older column encrypted_file I started setting it as null, new schema looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT,
    entityId varchar(50),
    encrypted_file mediumtext,
    created_at datetime,
    updated_at datetime,
    encrypted_file_v2 mediumtext
);
```

so it is storing all most same number of records per day before and after the change, but after making this changes what I observed that the disk storage utilisation has increased than before on the daily basis, I verified the size of the file being stored , it has reduced around 80-90%, but the overall disk utilisation has increased
sql engine is innodb

not able to figure out why is this happening , any idea about this behaviour ?

I tried this in local but not able to figure out exact behaviour of the problem.

Comment: You could try using [column compression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/storage-engine-independent-column-compression/) instead. It won't work on encrypted data (encrypted data can't be compressed), you could consider using [data-at-rest encryption](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/encryption-data-at-rest-encryption/) instead.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Available as of 10.3.  Good catch @Schwern

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are issues here.

First. do *not* store compressed or encrypted data in a `MEDIUMTEXT`, you will lose data.  Instead, use `MEDIUMBLOB`.

"Large" `TEXTs` and `BLOBs` are stored "off-record -- in 16KB blocks separate from the rest of the columns, which live in 16KB blocks.  A 20-byte pointer is used to access the text/blob from the main blocks.

Freeing up space in InnoDB is a tricky matter.  Mostly, any freed space is held onto until some other row (or off-record stuff) reuses the space.  There is some attempt to coalesce 'small' blocks.  The table size will never decrease, but may, after some time, be more compact.

Check the actual number of rows via `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl`.  Get the data's BTree size from `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl';`.  (Do not trust avg_row_size or num_rows.)  Divide.

After you have rebuilt the column, use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to clean up the horrible fragmentation you see.  (Caution: this command will take a long time -- ot copies the table over.)

Yes, your design is good.  Compressing (and optionally encrypting) text and storing in some size `BLOB` helps shrink disk space and probably helps with performance.

What kind of text do you have?  Most text I have seen shrinks only to 1/3 of original size.  Encryption is mostly 1:1.

Better yet, use *column* compression available since 10.3+.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/storage-engine-independent-column-compression/

Comment: text is XML, I checked for fragmentation also , it is very less, I am encrypting and then compressing the data and for the original column have not performed any operation , I started using the new column to store the compressed data and setting older column as null for any writes.

Comment: I'm serious about `BLOB`.  Have you successfully retrieved the data and converted it back to readable XML?

Comment: Yes , encryption and compression is done as part of the code and then wrtting it in db , have converted it XML and processed it also as part of read path.

Comment: @rich James with reference to your answer , if I have a row inserted , will db block a 32kb block and 40 bytes pointer every time , even if the values are null for both the mediumText cell ?

Comment: @Shiva - If the total row is < 8KB, the row will be entirely "on-record"; that is in the BTree indexed by the PRIMARY KEY.  Else, the largest cell(s) will be put in a different block, leaving a "pointer" to it.  So, compressed cell(s) have a better chance of not needing an extra disk hit to get the XML.  This "off-record" choice independently for each row.

Comment: @Shiva You're encrypting first, *then* compressing? The compression shouldn't work, the resulting file shouldn't be much smaller. If it is, it implies the encryption is not working (encrypted data is, effectively, random and random data cannot be compressed).

Comment: @Shiva Can we see how you're doing your encryption and compression and insert?

Comment: @Schwern I am compressing first which Is Gzip and then encrypting it.

Comment: `MEDIUMTEXT` will not handle such; you _must_ switch to `MEDIUMBOB`.

Comment: And will MEDIUMB be ideal for this use case , since it is more suitable to store binary data , choose MEDIUMTEXT because of this reason only.